# Understanding this SWf link

Tags: html, flash

I'd like to knwo what the parameters in the following SWF link froma HTML document mean:
`mprev_2k8.swf?thisId=smovie1&fName=composer_mp3_2977/swf&`

- `thisId=smovie1` — Sets thisId variable inside the SWF to "smovie1".
- `fName=composer_mp3_2977` — Sets fName to "composer_mp3_2977".
- `/swf&` — This I don't understand. Is it part of the value attributed to fName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything between two ampersands (`&`) is a single key/value pair. So,

```
fName=composer_mp3_2977/swf
```

means that the `fname` key has the value `composer_mp3_2977/swf`.